# Certain font weights not showing up

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Was trying to install Bebas (5 weights)from here: http://fontfabric.com/bebas-neue/, but only Thin Light and Bold show up when I open Photoshop. Is there something that I have to configure to show all 5 weights?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to configure anything. I installed the fonts just now and all five of them show up just fine. Make sure check the drop down box next to your selected font. See below.

[image]

Comment: Hey Nico, I did the same thing – but unfortunately only three show up. See here: ![http://i.imgur.com/dNGmoHj.png](http://i.imgur.com/dNGmoHj.png)

Comment: are you on windows or mac? Maybe that has something to do with it?!